# Use an angular directive inside another directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have created the below angular directives, **ChildDirective** that is used inside **ParentDirective**

```
var wizardModule = angular.module('Wizard', []);

wizardModule.directive('childDirective', function ($http, $templateCache, $compile, $parse) {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: [],
    compile: function (iElement, iAttrs, transclude) {
        iElement.append('child directive<br />');
    }
}
})

wizardModule.directive('parentDirective', function ($http, $compile) {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    compile: function (element, attrs) {
        var x = '<child-directive></child-directive><child-directive></child-directive>';
        element.append(x);
    }
}
```

This was working normally and several child directives appeared.

I wanted to update the **ParentDirective**, to get the list of **childDirectives** from the server. Hence I updated the **ParentDirective** code to do an ajax call and then draw the **ChildDirectives**

```
var elem;
wizardModule.directive('parentDirective', function ($http, $compile) {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    compile: function (element, attrs) {
        var controllerurl = attrs.controllerurl;
        elem = element;

        if (controllerurl) {
            $http.get(controllerurl + '/GetWizardItems').
            success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                var x = '<child-directive></child-directive><child-directive></child-directive>';
                elem.append(x);
                $compile(x);
            });
        }
    }
}
});
```

The problem is that the **childDirectives** does not appear any more, although in the debeggur it is entering to the compile method of the **childDirective**

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You have to link the compiled element to the scope. And since you're no longer modifying the template element you should append the new elements to the linked element. YOu can do it like this:

```js
var elem;
wizardModule.directive('parentDirective', function ($http, $compile) {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    compile: function (element, attrs) {
        var controllerurl = attrs.controllerurl;
        elem = element;

        if (controllerurl) {
          return function(scope,element){
            $http.get(controllerurl + '/GetWizardItems').
            success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                var x = angular.element('<child-directive></child-directive><child-directive></child-directive>');
                element.append(x);
                $compile(x)(scope);
            });
          }
        }
    }
}
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried it, but unfortunately it did not work.

Comment: I've made a small correction, think it should work var x = **angular.element(**'<child-directive></child-directive><child-directive></child-directive>'**)**;

Comment: angular.element(), solved the problem. and there is no need to link it to the scope.
so $compile(x) is enough.
Coooool

Comment: This particular directive (`child-directive`) has no link function, no controller and no bindings in the template so it'll "work", but you really should link it to a scope

Comment: +1 : lifesaving answer!!! if i only could i would give 100 points for this answer! thanks! it works perfectly :)

Comment: Where is scope coming from?