# Directive possible conflict?

Tags: angularjs

### The goal

Run two directives at once.

### The problem

The `link` fragment from my `category` directive isn't calling/working.

### Details

Here you are my directives:

```
app.directive('navigators', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {},
        controller: function($scope) {
            var categories = $scope.categories = [];

            this.add = function(category) {
                categories.push(category);
            };
        },
        templateUrl: 'navigators/structure.volt'
    };
}).directive('category', function() {
    return {
        require: '^navigators',
        transclude: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            name: '@'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attributes, navigatorsController) {
            console.log('Performing some tests.');
        }
    };
});
```

My HTML that uses these directives:

```
<navigators>
    <category name="Home">
        <!-- things goes here -->
    </category>
    <category name="Downloads">
        <!-- other things goes here -->
    </category>
</navigators>
```

And finally, the `structure.volt` (normal HTML markup):

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="category in categories">
            {{category.name}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

### Diagnostics

- No error messages are showing in the browser's (Chrome) console;
- Everything that's inside of `structure.volt` is displaying, except — obviously — what's inside of `ng-repeat`;
- When I remove the `templateUrl` from the first directive (`navigators`), I can see "Performing some tests." on the console.

### Playground

Guys, I can't turn on an on-the-fly example of my problem for you because my case uses `templateUrl` and I don't see any chance to use it on jsFiddle.

Comment: Maybe (i am not sure if i understood you right) can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16787276/use-an-angular-directive-inside-another-directive

Comment: You might be missing a `ng-transclude` in the `structure.volt` code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify where the transcluded content should be inserted in your `structure.volt` template, e.g.

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="category in categories">
            {{category.name}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div ng-transclude></div>
```