# How to call another directive from directive angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to call `alertForm` directive in `loginForm` directive. Where I want call 'alertForm' directive in 'loginForm' is highlighted as `//i want to call here`

alertForm directive

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('alertForm', function () {
        return {
            templateUrl: 'app/directives/alert/alertForm.html',
            restrict: 'E',
                scope: {
                   topic: '=topic',
                   description: '=description'
                },
            controller: function($scope) {
                $scope.words = [];

                this.showAlert = function() {
                    $scope.description.push("hello");
                };
            }
        };
    });
```

loginForm directive

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('loginForm', function() {
        return {
            templateUrl: 'app/directives/loginForm/loginForm.html',
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                successCallback: '&',
                errorCallback: '&',
                emailField: '='
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            },
            controller: function ($rootScope, $scope, authenticationService) {
                $scope.loginFormData = {};
                $scope.inProgress = false;
                $scope.onLogin = function (form) {
                    if (form.$valid) {
                        $scope.inProgress = true;
                        authenticationService.loginUser('password', $scope.loginFormData).then(function () {
                            $scope.successCallback({formData: $scope.loginFormData});
                        }, function (err) {
                            $scope.inProgress = false;
                            if (err.message) {
                                **// i want to call here**
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use an angular directive inside another directive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16787276/use-an-angular-directive-inside-another-directive)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `require` config of directive.

> When a directive requires a controller, it receives that controller as
>   the fourth argument of its link function. Ref : [Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

You can implement this in your code

```
angular.module(‘myApp')
    .directive('loginForm', function() {
        return {
            templateUrl: 'app/directives/loginForm/loginForm.html',
            restrict: 'E',
            require:'alertForm',
            scope: {
                successCallback: '&',
                errorCallback: '&',
                emailField: '='
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attrs, alertFormCtrl) {
                scope.alertFormCtrl = alertFormCtrl;
            },
            controller: function ($rootScope, $scope, authenticationService) {
                $scope.loginFormData = {};
                $scope.inProgress = false;
                $scope.onLogin = function (form) {
                    if (form.$valid) {
                        $scope.inProgress = true;
                        authenticationService.loginUser('password', $scope.loginFormData).then(function () {
                            $scope.successCallback({formData: $scope.loginFormData});
                        }, function (err) {
                            $scope.inProgress = false;
                            if (err.message) {
                                // Calling showAlert function of alertFormCtrl
                               $scope.alertFormCtrl.showAlert();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    });
```

Comment: where "alertFormCtrl" coming from? Do I need to create new controller called "alertFormCtrl"?

Comment: @ppshein Read the 2nd line of my answer.

Comment: @ppshein I've added require:'alertForm' config. This injects alertFormCtrl to the link function. So you don't need to create new controller 'alertFormCtrl '.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line in the `app/directives/loginForm/loginForm.html` :

`<alertForm topic="something" description = "something" ng-if="showAlert"></alertForm>`

Now inside the loginForm directive's controller : **// i want to call here**
use

`$scope.showAlert = true;`

Note: you can use some variable to setup the topic and description as well inside the alertForm.