# Marking directive as required

Tags: angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive

I am using Angular 1.5

I have a form that has several required fields in it. For most of them I am just using `<select required></select>` but there is one field that is a custom directive that is written and maintained by another team.

Is there a way to mark a directive as required from outside of it, or am I going to have to request a change to the directive? I already tried adding `required` and `ng-required="true"` but my form doesn't seem to recognize it as a required field.

Comment: If you cannot control the directive itself, you can have a custom validation implemented by having a directive that implements a custom validation whereby it checks for a value/property in the given custom directive and puts a custom flag to denote an error if it is null, `''` (or falsy).

Comment: Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33773492/how-to-call-another-directive-from-directive-angularjs It demonstrates how to call a directive from another directive.

Comment: You could write your own directive that taps into their ngModel and adds validation. Probably better to have the team that wrote it implement the validation, though, since they can then apply the 'ng-invalid' class to the appropriate child controls.