# Directive inside templateUrl of another directive and passing attribute

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-directive

I'm having two directives and I'm trying to call one directive inside another directive's templateUrl with some attribute but I'm not able to get the compiled attribute value in the second directive. Code is like this:

**1st directive**

```
app.directive('myDir', function() {
   return {
     link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
         scope.myVal='hello';
     },
     templateUrl: 'directive1.html',
     scope: {}
  }
```

**directive.html**

```
<div>
   <child-dir attrval="{{myVal}}"></child-dir>
<div>
```

**2nd directive**

```
app.directive('childDir', function() {
       return {
         templateUrl: template(element,attrs) {
             alert(attrs.attrval);
         },
         scope: {}
      }
```

Here, **attrs.attrval** is coming like this **{{myVal}}**.
but I want the value **hello**. Can anyone help me?
Please note two things here:

1) I'm using templateUrl.
2) I'm passing a scope variable's value as an attribute to the child directive.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use an angular directive inside another directive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16787276/use-an-angular-directive-inside-another-directive)

Comment: Yeah it is similar but it is not duplicate. The example that you showed is not having the following things: 1) templateUrl  2) value passed in attributes.

Comment: **Can Anyone Help???**

Comment: This is not a 100% duplicate, as that one talks about a "simple" directive with no additional attributes/model/scope. Here the question is about having a child directive *with attribute*

Comment: I have the same problem, did you manage to fix it? :(

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and finally found the solution (probably not the best, but it's working for me). Your example is a litte bit different from mine, but I suppose in your example would be:

Parent directive and directive.html equals, but child directive:

```
app.directive('childDir', function() {
   return {
     templateUrl: template(element,attrs) {
           attrs.$observe("attrval", function(){
             alert(attrs.attrval);
           });
     },
     scope: {}
  }
```

When template is set in parent directive the value is not set yet, but child directive is trying to use it. With 'observe', child directive can force refresh when attrval is really set.

If not works for you, tell me and I will post parts of my code in case it would be useful.